# TextView and ProgressBar value not updated after backpress of the current activity then come back to that activity

Tags: android

I can set the updated progress value into progressbar and textview value inside the progressbar at first time. But after i left current activity and come back to that activity again. It become with its default value which are specified at xml as follows

```
        <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/batteryLevel"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/battery_level"
    android:max="100"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/devName"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/batteryLevelTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OFF"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/batteryLevel"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/batteryLevel"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/batteryLevel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/batteryLevel"/>
```

```
            String battProgress = progress + "%";
            batteryTv.setText(battProgress);
            batteryTv.invalidate();
            batteryTv.requestLayout();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                batteryLevel.setProgress(progress, true);
            } else {
                batteryLevel.setProgress(progress);
            }
```

I use android api level 28. Can anyone helps me with this issue?

Comment: would you plz share the full code of activity.

Comment: You should call the update progress commands in `onResume` event of the Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be an issue due to **`Activity Lifecycle`**.
If I assume correct It is happening due to any one of the following:
1) You are setting the progress data in `onResume` which is getting called again when the second Activity has finished and you navigate back.
2) You are recreating the Progress activity from Activity 2 After you exit, Instead of just passing updated data.

Comment: yes it is correct due to activity lifecycle. It was fixed by changing progressbar and textview var as static. reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433583/textview-stops-updating-after-bringing-activity-back-to-the-front